# Is it possible to remove BitLocker functionality from Windows?

Tags: windows, malware, bitlocker, ransomware

Is there any way to remove BitLocker functionality from Windows?

BitLocker has recently been used by ransomware to lock a friend's drive. He is now supposed to pay bitcoin to some hackers to get the password.

I don't use BitLocker and would like to remove this potential attack vector completely from my computer. Yes, I understand that BitLocker is not the only method for encrypting a drive's contents within from Windows.

I'm interested in **removing the ability to use Bitlocker to encrypt a drive**. Think of it as "uninstalling" bitlocker.

In particular, I'm referring to Windows 7 Ultimate.

---

Note: This question is **NOT** about removing Bitlocker encryption from an already-encrypted drive.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't exactly know how you do this but I believe the option would be in the Group Policy Editor (start > run > `gpedit.msc`). I hope that helps.  Note that a virus could just re-enable Bitlocker if it runs as an administrator but the author probably won't think to do that.

Comment: Are you using an edition of Windows that even supports enabling BitLocker?  Update your question.

Comment: @SteveRukuts that just removes Bitlocker from the control panel.

Comment: Consider the problem you are trying to solve: preventing data loss due to malware. It would be more effective to implement a backup strategy that ensures you can recover your data, *regardless* the method used to destroy it. Disabling BitLocker may block one attack vector, but a good backup will block *all* like-kind attacks.

Comment: @Ramhound every version since Vista supports Bitlocker. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @pbarney - Incorrect.  Only Vista Ultimate fully supported BitLocker.  Vista Home Premium didn't support it.  Vista Home Premium could only view the contents of an encrypted volume  *Windows 10 Home is the same way by the way.*  [Comparison Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO3Vn.png).  There is a discontinued application that allowed you to read BitLocker encrypted volumes on Windows XP.  Does it really matter though?  **Knowing what edition of Windows the author is using is important.**

Comment: @pbarney - Can you update your question with exactly what version of Windows (include detail such as "Home", "Home Premium", "Ultimate" etc.). As it stands this question is, at best, going to get lots of low quality, guesses of things to try and not going to get you the answer you need, or provide the community a quality answer. Additionally, you state that the question is not about removing BitLocker from an already BitLocker encrypted drive... what other BitLocker methods are there? BitLocker can only encrypt a system, data or removable drives/volumes.

Comment: @Kinnectus I updated the question with *my* version of Windows, but I would think the right answer would be applicable for any version of Windows that has Bitlocker. Maybe I'm wrong. Regardless, I'm interested in **removing the ability to use Bitlocker to encrypt a drive**. Think of it as "uninstalling" bitlocker.

Answer (score 2):

If your disk is a Dynamic disk, then Bitlocker cannot encrypt it. Bitlocker only works on Basic disks.

To convert your disk to a dynamic disk:

1. Run diskmgmt.msc as Administrator
2. Right click on the Partition you wish to convert to Dynamic and select `Convert to Dynamic Disk`

Bitlocker now cannot encrypt the disk. You can see [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-frequently-asked-questions) article on the statement of Bitlocker not supporting Dynamic disks.

Comment: However, there’s a reason: Dynamic Disks come with quite a lot of limitations, especially with interoperability.

Comment: @DanielB true. This was the only effective answer I could come up with tho as the other is use a separate account for admin tasks to avoid account escalation.